# "~において、..." vs. "~にとって、..." differences?

Tags: set-phrases

I'd like to ask about the difference between "~において、..." and "~にとって、...":

example #1

> 1. アジア地域{ちいき} **にとって** は、日本{にほん}は超大国{ちょうたいこく}です。
> 2. アジア地域 **において** は、日本は超大国です。

example #2

> 1. 中国人{ちゅうごくじん} **にとって** は、漢字{かんじ}は難しくない{むずかしくない}。
> 2. 中国人 **において** は、漢字は難しくない。

thank you.

Comment: @snailboat I am pretty sure I've read/heard the phrase "~におきまして、~です。" A google shows some info about that. But, that confuses me. I didn't think you can say something like "お酒をたくさん飲みまして、楽しかったんです。". It should be "たくさん飲んで、楽しかったです。" Of course, I am not sure at all.

Comment: @user312440 「〜まして」 is fine. You should separate that into a different question so it doesn't muddle this one.

Comment: I think both of these アジア examples are okay (although there is a slight difference in meaning). In the 中国人 example (you deleted), only 「中国人にとって」 was acceptable. Perhaps you can revive 中国人にとって so that people can explain this issue better.

Comment: @naruto Since "にとって" and "において" are actually both ok in the 地域 example, then that pretty much proves the value of stackexchange's peer review feature. My assuming that the opinion of any given native speaker is fact is not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example #1

> 1. Asian countries think that Japan is an extremely large countrie.
> 2. Japan is one of the largest countris in Asia.

Example #2

> 1. Chinese feel that Kanji is not difficult.
> 2. (Does not make sense.)

“AにとってB” means “A feels that B”.
“AにおいてB” means

- “In A, B”, if A is a place or a time.
- “About A, B”, if A is a subject.

Answer (score 0):

アジア地域にとっては、日本は超大国です。 → For the Asian region, Japan is a superpower.

アジア地域においては、日本は超大国です。 → In the Asian region, Japan is a superpower.

中国人にとっては、漢字は難しくない。 → For Chinese people, kanji is not so difficult.

中国人においては、漢字は難しくない。 → Among Chinese people, kanji is not so difficult.

にとって is "for".

において is "in".