# My Issue: What is おいて in 安価なインターネットVPNにおいても遅延やゆらぎのない高品質かつリアルタイムな通信を実現し?

Tags: grammar, words

Full Text: 本製品は、IPsecとQoS機能の同時利用により、安価なインターネットVPNにおいても遅延やゆらぎのない高品質かつリアルタイムな通信を実現し、IP電話サービスを高い通話品質で利用できます。

My Issue: What is おいて in 安価なインターネットVPNにおいても遅延やゆらぎのない高品質かつリアルタイムな通信を実現し?

My understanding of the text: "Implements real-time, high-quality communications on low-price internet VPNs without any latency or fluctuation." but I do not know what to make of おいて.

Comment: You may be able to find the answer to your question – or at least refine your question – by looking up **において** (not おいて) in a dictionary. There are also some existing questions on this site that you may find useful. Try https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15412/are-these-phrases-interchangeable-に関して-に対して-において-について-における and https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19192/において-vs-にとって-differences and https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/54004/why-are-において-における-necessary

Comment: Also: Not what you're asking, but your English translation ignores the particle も, and the prepositional phrase "without any latency or fluctuation" is **misplaced**. (It appears to modify "VPNs," when it should be modifying "communications.")

Comment: @Nanigashi I am of the same thought regarding "modifying" concern. I left the も particle to translate it after understanding the において term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ～において is a stiff expression that marks a place/setting/situation and roughly means "under ～ (situation)", "in ～ (settings)", "in the context of ～", "at ～", etc. も is just "also" or "even". It is often interchangeable with で, but it is more explicit and can avoid ambiguity in longer sentences.

- 高熱の環境において in high-heat environments
- 序盤において in the early stages (of something)
- 実験において in experimental settings
- 高度10000mにおいて at an altitude of 10000 meters

Thus 安価なインターネットVPNにおいても means "even in the low-price VPN environment".

Comment: Thank you for your help!